# Sending null from C++/CLI to managed C#

Tags: c++, visual-c++, enums, clr, nullable

I have a C++/CLI wrapper to be able to call C# code. In the C# code I have a method which accepts a nullable enum as parameter, but I can't figure out how I can call this method with a null parameter from my wrapper.

C# method:

```
public int DoSomething(MyEnum? option)
{
    if (option != null)
        //Do something
    else
        //Do something else 
}
```

The C++ function calling DoSomething():

```
int MyMethod(int option)
{
    int myVal;
    if (option > -1)
    {
        myVal = component->DoSomething((CSharpNameSpace::MyEnum)option); //This works
    }
    else
    {
        myVal = component->DoSomething(??); //I want to send null here
    }
}
```

I tried several things but nothing has worked so far:

- Sending 0, NULL, or nullptr won't compile
- (CSharpNameSpace::MyEnum)NULL is setting the value to 0 of course

I don't have control of the C# code, so I can't change the enum to have a none value or anything like that.

Comment: What is the actual type `MyEnum` in the C++ code, and how did you figure that it is the same as the `MyEnum` type in C#?

Comment: It's actually being used as CSharpNameSpace::MyEnum...I'll update he code...

Comment: is all-lowercase `null` defined in your C++ env?

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota nope

Comment: @SeverusSnape Your edit really doesn't help.  What is `CSharpNameSpace`?  And if it is a C++ class that is supposed to mimic the same in C#, you would think that there is a 'null" setter for it.  If not, it is lacking since it didn't implement the full functionality of the C# type.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie CSharpNameSpace is the namespace of the C# class.

Comment: @SeverusSnape You claim you're writing native C++, but nowhere does `CSharpNameSpace` exist in native C++ code. Are you sure you're writing native C++ code, and not C++/CLI code?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok so my application is in native C++, but as I said I am writing a CLI wrapper as a "bridge" between my native C++ app and the C# code. The code example is from my C++/CLI wrapper.

Comment: @RawN ok i suppose mentioning my native c++ app was a bit was misleading...i've updated the question. Now that it should be clear, do you have any suggestion for the problem? :-)

Comment: You can wrap the action of calling the c# function with null enum paramenter in a new C# function `nullParaCall`, and `nullParaCall` has no parameter, then wrap it using CLI, then call `nullParaCall` in C++ code. But I guess it should exist more elegent solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nullable types don't get any syntax love in C++/CLI, very unlike C#.  The basic obstacle you run into is that there is no implicit conversion from nullptr to Nullable.  A simple way is to rely on the default constructor:

```
int MyMethod(int option)
{
    Nullable<ClassLibrary1::MyEnum> enu;
    if (option > -1) enu = safe_cast<ClassLibrary1::MyEnum>(option);
    return component->DoSomething(enu);
}
```

Comment: When I do that, and say option is -2, then the C# method will get -2 value and it fails the null check :-(

Comment: That is only possible in a Harry Potter novel.  You somehow missed the if() statement.

Comment: So this actually works! I was doing exactly as you said BUT it failed for me. Got the dev responsible for the C# bit and found a bug in his code! Double win!